# Accidently removed Digicert certificate from mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, ssl, https, certificate

After I upgraded my macbook air to latest version of Mac 10.9.2
I was constantly being rejected from accessing Github, with a strange error page showing 'certificate invalid'.

I tried to google for the solution, and found a post telling others to remove Digicert certificate from the keychain application.

As a happy reader, I applied the solution and the problem was safely gone away, at least I thought so.

Although I was able to access github page without previous error,
a new error cropped up, "Failed to load resource::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE".
I was able to load the content of the page perfectly, but at the same time, wasn't able to load related css and js file due to the aforementioned error.

After messing around with some quick google searches,
I am guessing the action of deleting Digicert certificate to be the root problem,
and want to restore the certificate.

Am I guessing right?
If not, what should I do to resolve this problem?
If yes, how can I restore the Digicert certificate?

Note:
I am using Google Chrome as a browser.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. I used the option to reset my keychain and now the digicert is gone from the system roots. I found a similar thread on apple stackexchange, maybe it will help us: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123150/i-updated-to-10-9-2-and-now-ssl-is-broken-how-do-i-fix-this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me:

(chrome, OsX)

1. Open **Keychain.app**
2. Search "digicert" in the top-right corner of Keychain.app
3. Select all digicert certificates and remove them with right click and context menu (http://screencast.com/t/2T4f1XQa0Xu)
4. Go here http://digicert.com/digicert-root-certificates.htm
5. Find on page and Download **DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA** certificate
6. When downloaded - click on it and install it into your keychain
7. Restart your chrome

Answer (score 1):

Manually installing the same update again worked for me - http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1726